# Generate combinations that add up to a target value

Tags: code-golf, permutations

### Challenge

Suppose you have a list of numbers, and a target value. Find the set of all combinations of your numbers which add up to the target value, returning them as list indices.

### Input and Output

The input will take a list of numbers (not necessarily unique) and a target summation number. The output will be a set of non-empty lists, each list containing integer values corresponding to the position of the values in the original input list.

### Examples

```
Input: values = [1, 2, 1, 5], target = 8
Output: [ [0,1,3], [1,2,3] ]

Input: values = [4.8, 9.5, 2.7, 11.12, 10], target = 14.8
Output: [ [0,4] ]

Input: values = [7, 8, 9, -10, 20, 27], target = 17
Output: [ [1,2], [0,3,4], [3,5] ]

Input: values = [1, 2, 3], target = 7
Output: [ ]
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75734/67312), possibly a dupe.

Comment: I think this is a dupe but I would rather close the older one because it is outdated.

Comment: Do floating point numbers really add something to the challenge? Not sure what the consensus is, but they will probably lead to precision errors in many languages.

Comment: I was intending to allow for floating points, yes

Comment: Bleh, indices? I think this would be a nicer challenge returning a list of values, though I guess that raises a question with how repeated values are dealt with in subsets.

Comment: @HeebyJeebyMan Have you "close the older one"?

Comment: @user202729 I have voted to now.  Prior I was unable to because this one had no answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
ηλfo=¹ṁ⁰tṖ
```

1-indexed. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9odXNr///Ot867Zm89wrnhuYHigbB04bmW////MP9bMSwxLC01LDMsLTIsMl0)

### Explanation

```
ηλfo=¹ṁ⁰tṖ  Inputs are a number n (explicit, accessed with ¹) and a list x (implicit).
η           Act on the incides of x
 λ          using this function:
         Ṗ   Take all subsets,
        t    remove the first one (the empty subset),
  f          and keep those that satisfy this:
      ṁ⁰      The sum of the corresponding elements of x
   o=¹        equals n.
```

This uses the latest addition to Husk, `η` (act on indices).
The idea is that `η` takes a higher order function `α` (here the inline lambda function) and a list `x`, and calls `α` on the indexing function of `x` (which is `⁰` in the above program) and the indices of `x`.
For example, `ṁ⁰` takes a subset of indices, maps indexing to `x` over them and sums the results.

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 96 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(list)(target)`.

```js
a=>s=>a.reduce((b,_,x)=>[...b,...b.map(y=>[...y,x])],[[]]).filter(b=>!b.reduce((p,i)=>p-a[i],s))
```

#### Test cases

This would fail on the 2nd test case if 4.8 and 10 were swapped because of an IEEE 754 precision error -- i.e. `14.8 - 4.8 - 10 == 0` but `14.8 - 10 - 4.8 != 0`. I think [this is fine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14459/58563), although there may be a more relevant reference somewhere in meta.

```js
let f =

a=>s=>a.reduce((b,_,x)=>[...b,...b.map(y=>[...y,x])],[[]]).filter(b=>!b.reduce((p,i)=>p-a[i],s))

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 2, 1, 5])(8)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([4.8, 9.5, 2.7, 11.12, 10])(14.8)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([7, 8, 9, -10, 20, 27])(17)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1, 2, 3])(7)))
```

#### Commented

```js
a => s =>                 // given an array a[] of length N and an integer s
  a.reduce((b, _, x) =>   // step #1: build the powerset of [0, 1, ..., N-1]
    [ ...b,               //   by repeatedly adding to the previous list b[]
      ...b                //   new arrays made of:
      .map(y =>           //     all previous entries stored in y[]
        [...y, x]         //     followed by the new index x
      )                   //   leading to:
    ],                    //   [[]] -> [[],[0]] -> [[],[0],[1],[0,1]] -> ...
    [[]]                  //   we start with a list containing an empty array
  )                       // end of reduce()
  .filter(b =>            // step #2: filter the powerset
    !b.reduce((p, i) =>   //   keeping only entries b
      p - a[i],           //     for which sum(a[i] for i in b)
      s                   //     is equal to s
    )                     //   end of reduce()
  )                       // end of filter()
```

Comment: Not one but two `reduce`s? I've got to upvote this.

Comment: @Neil The lesser known "reduceMapReduce"

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
(=1#.t#])<@I.@#t=.1-[:i.&.#.1"0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0HD1lBZr0Q5VtPGwVPPQbnEVs9QN9oqU09NT1nPUMngf2pyRr6ChUKagqGCERCbcoEFDE30QGIg0lLPVMFIz1zB0FDPEKjCQAGqwhwobw7UaakQDxQ0AiJzqJQ51DRjhf8A)

```
                  1-[:i.&.#.1"0         Make a list of all masks
                                        for the input list. We flip the bits
                                        to turn the unnecessary (0...0)         
                                        into (1...1) that would be missing.
                                        Define it as t.

(=1#.t#])                               Apply the masks, sum and
                                        compare with the target

         <@I.@#                         Turn the matching masks into 
                                        lists of indices
```

Comment: I feel like an explicit definition would help given all of the compositions, but unfortunately I only got the same length: `4 :'<@I.t#~x=1#.y#~t=.#:}.i.2^#y'`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81Wz0TBSt3GwVOvRLmuwtZQWa9Sua7EVk/ZqlYvU88oTrlS/X9qcka@goVCmoKhghEQm3KBBQxN9EBiINJSz1TBSM9cwdBQzxCowkABqsIcKG8O1GmpEA8UNAIic6iUOdQ0Y4X/AA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 110 bytes

```python
lambda a,n:[b for b in[[i for i in range(len(a))if j&1<<i]for j in range(2**len(a))]if sum(a[c]for c in b)==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBCsIwEEDRq8xKkjKbBASR5iRjFpPa6JR2WmJdePrYFsHdh/@Wz/qc1dccbnXkKd0ZGPVKCfJcIIEokRwtW0NhffRm7NWwtZJhOLm2lbj/4f990/xI3MzrPRmm7kDdjpINQWNdiugK2ZBDjw7PES@2fgE)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```r
function(l,k){N=combn
o={}
for(i in I<-1:sum(l|1))o=c(o,N(I,i,,F)[N(l,i,sum)==k])
o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYvBCoMwEETv@Yo97sIajLTYirkWvPgDpZcGAkHNgq0n67en62EYmPdmLRH6qsQth2@SjDNPtI8@yPLORvx@mCgrJkgZhr5y3WdbcP45IvEBhUccODE/6DnqNbFi8n56kZGjRAx4sTeGu70yNLZlcM66RqsmdorInI7up8RQuVq9M63ylsof)

1-indexed.

`combn` usually returns a `matrix`, but setting `simplify=F` returns a `list` instead, allowing us to `c`oncatenate all the results together. `combn(I,i,,F)` returns all combinations of indices, and we take `N(l,i,sum)==k` as an index into that list to determine those which equal `k`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
m, à f_x!gU ¥V
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=bSwg4CBmX3ghZ1UgpVY=&input=WzcsIDgsIDksIC0xMCwgMjAsIDI3XQoxNwoKLVI=)

#### How it works

```
m, à f_x!gU ¥V   Implicit: U = input array, V = target sum
m,               Turn U into a range [0, 1, ..., U.length - 1].
   à             Generate all combinations of this range.
     f_          Filter to only the combinations where
       x           the sum of
        !gU        the items at these indices in U
            ¥V     equals the target sum.
                 Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: Nice trick with `m,`. I had `Êo à k@VnXx@gX` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 5):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>104</s> <s>102</s> 98 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@n=[[]:[[i:b]\\i<-[0..n-1],b<- @i]]
?l n=[e\\e<-tl(@(length l))|sum(map((!!)l)e)==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc2xCoMwFEDR3a94bgkY0UIXUXRoh0I3xyRD1NQGXp5SY6HQb2/qdJcDd0RrKPpl2tGCN46i8@vyCtCH6UrvpKNGSl1J6apBK@VqIYs8J1HqbKgFdE7rpEU4lFXK1iIg6xhamsMTkPPvtnvmzcpYmnLkljcN6dgHcxwaaEGWGZwyEEfOGor4Gx9o5i2K2z1ePmS8G7c/)

Comment: `[1, 2, -1, 5] 0  --> [[],[2,0]]` A set of non-empty lists is required.

Comment: @FrownyFrog Fixed

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ị³S=
JŒPçÐf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//4buLwrNTPQpKxZJQw6fDkGb///8xLDIsMSw1/zg)

1-indexed. 4 bytes spent on returning indices rather than just the elements themselves.

-1 byte thanks to user202729
-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//4buLwrNTPeKBtApKxZJQw4fDkGb///8xLDIsMSw1/zg)

Comment: @user202729 Cool, thanks!

Comment: -1 byte: The `⁴` is unnecessary if you use `ç` rather than `Ç`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan o good catch thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

```hs
x#t=[i|i<-tail$concat<$>mapM(\z->[[],[z]])[0..length x-1],t==sum[x!!k|k<-i]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1LCoMwEIDhfU8xRRctJCFpK1ow3qAnSGcRrNRgfFBTEPHuaaQboV3MLOb/YGo9NpW13k@Rk8osJqdOGxuXfVdql8dFq4fb4T7TQikkakY8Ks6Yrbqnq2GiAomTcny3atrvm6XJqUH0rTYdSHj0O4DhZToHMShB4EQg7ASjbBsuLCNwZUnoLA1CMLFCjpEIaStDXSkBKnjQ66RBpb9vzhj9udLvd@4/)

Comment: `[1, 2, -1, 5]#0 --> [[],[0,2]]` A set of non-empty lists is required.

Comment: @FrownyFrog Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 43 bytes

1-indexed.

```
Pick[s=Subsets;s@Range@Tr[1^#],Tr/@s@#,#2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3BCsIwDIDhu08RGHiKdZ2OTmTQRxi6W6lQRzeLbIe2nsRnrymC7JAc8n@Q2cSHnU10g0kjtJA6NzxVaK@ve7AxnIO8mGWysveK3wqNvd/LIAssKr1NnXdLlKN6c4QKgXb9QWj05h@OrEE4sZo6EyQ44xmWxDi1laSaKcKOl6TziKzEyvzeHOgsdPoC)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 144 bytes

```python
lambda a,t:[[e for e,_ in x]for r in range(len(a))for x in combinations(list(enumerate(a)),r+1)if sum(y for _,y in x)==t]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsIwEEX3nmKWic6miiBCT1JLSTXRgSRTJlNoTx9Jd/8/Hm/Z9cf5VkP/qtGl@ePAoT6HwUNgAY8TUIZtbEfaFJe/3kSfjbO20a3RN6eZslPiXEykosbnNXlx6puHcuksBShrMvsRnnA/wrbvdTwF4QSkXpQ5FqC0sOi5LkJZTTBDh1fs8D7iw9r6Bw)

0-indexed. 44 bytes spent on returning indices rather than just the elements themselves.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>18</s> 15 bytes

```
hiᶠ⊇Shᵐ+~t?∧Stᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpofbFjzc1Vn7cOuE/xmZQM6jrvbgDCBPu67E/lHH8uASkMz/6OhoQx0FIx0FIGkaq6NgAcTR0SZ6FjoKlnqmQBk9c6CcoZ4hSIkBUNIQKAdWAxQHKdJRiDc0AKoDYXOQvDlYFmKoMZBtHhsLAA)

*-3 bytes because it now [works as a generator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/85334).* (It's probably possible to golf more, but working around the need to use indices is awkward.)

```
    S              The variable S
   ⊇               is a sublist of
  ᶠ                the list of all
 i                 pairs [element, index] from
h                  the first element of
                   the input;
     hᵐ            the first elements of each pair
       +           add up to
        ~t         the last element of
          ?        the input
           ∧       which isn't necessarily
            S      S,
             tᵐ    from which the last elements of each pair
                   are output.
```

Comment: `hiᶠ⊇z+ʰXh~t?∧Xt` comes out to the same length.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 45 bytes

```perl6
->\a,\b{grep {a[$_].sum==b},^a .combinations}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##bZJLboMwEIb3nOJfRFFQBwvybIWIOECX3REaAXErpPAQdqpGESfrrhejYyfpS7GEGY/n/2Y8diu7/XI4KIm3pShCpzpiXDQ7iWjw1puMNvnptZMtTlky2qZCHaooynt6ziCKpsrLOtNlU6t@YGGspdKIMHGACf6OJCBMCTwvUgLuyfiQ@BTQjB28PWUD6TnaJYtI5oIDH8SCtWLF6kAEBuKzIrB7FjHnZfov3xVhc7PUcAhe4DPKfCuDWF2q4OSmBp9mlpXMaGFK@YW4dRZTNy6IFLcHI9zQUYcc3K2qqRl3F2/h4oR4@/khVNNp/j2WSlvbWugdcyFP3M3QafdZzRptFy9Nd@myt8YkzmiUUyzfW1louWMo11sqbydluz/CXOM5xhXjc3rCd/SP6xrT8lMInX74Ag)

### Expanded:

```perl6
->
  \a, # input list
  \b, # input target
{

  grep

  {
      a[ $_ ].sum # use the list under test as indexes into ｢a｣
    ==
      b
  },

  ^a              # Range upto ｢a｣ (uses ｢a｣ as a number)
  .combinations   # get all of the combinations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 49 chars, 98 bytes

```
{∨/b←⍺=+/¨{∊⍵⊂w}¨n←{⍵⊤⍨k⍴2}¨⍳¯1+2*k←≢w←⍵:⍸¨b/n⋄⍬}
```

1-indexed; test:

```
  f←{∨/b←⍺=+/¨{∊⍵⊂w}¨n←{⍵⊤⍨k⍴2}¨⍳¯1+2*k←≢w←⍵:⍸¨b/n⋄⍬}
  ⎕fmt 8 f 1 2 1 5
┌2──────────────┐
│┌3────┐ ┌3────┐│
││2 3 4│ │1 2 4││
│└~────┘ └~────┘2
└∊──────────────┘
  ⎕fmt   14.8  f  4.8 9.5 2.7 11.12 10
┌1────┐
│┌2──┐│
││1 5││
│└~──┘2
└∊────┘
  ⎕fmt 17 f 7, 8, 9, ¯10, 20, 27
┌3──────────────────┐
│┌2──┐ ┌2──┐ ┌3────┐│
││4 6│ │2 3│ │1 4 5││
│└~──┘ └~──┘ └~────┘2
└∊──────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt 7 f 1 2 3
┌0┐
│0│
└~┘
```

comment:

```
{∨/b←⍺=+/¨{∊⍵⊂w}¨n←{⍵⊤⍨k⍴2}¨⍳¯1+2*k←≢w←⍵:⍸¨b/n⋄⍬}
                             ⍳¯1+2*k←≢w←⍵         copy ⍵ in w, len(⍵) in k, return 1..2^(k-1) 
                 n←{⍵⊤⍨k⍴2}¨                     traslate in binary each element of  1..2^(k-1) and assign the result to n
          {∊⍵⊂w}¨                                for each binary element of n return the elemets of ⍵ in the place where there are the 1s
    b←⍺=+/¨                                       sum them and see if the sum is ⍺, that binary array saved in b
  ∨/                                     :⍸¨b/n   if or/b, get all the elements of n that are 1s for array b, and calculate each all indexs
                                               ⋄⍬ else return Zilde as void set
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
fqvzs@LQTyU
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqvzs%40LQTyU&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A9&debug=0), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqvzs%40LQTyU&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C%202%2C%201%2C%205%5D%0A8%0A%5B4.8%2C%209.5%2C%202.7%2C%2011.12%2C%2010%5D%0A14.8%0A%5B7%2C%208%2C%209%2C%20-10%2C%2020%2C%2027%5D%0A17%0A%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0A7&debug=0&input_size=2).

```
fqvzs@LQTyUQ   Implicit: Q=input 1 (list of numbers), z=input 2 (target value, as string)
               Trailing Q inferred
          UQ   Generate range [0-<length of Q>)
         y     Powerset of the above
f              Keep elements of the above, as T, when the following is truthy:
      L T        Map elements of T...
     @ Q         ... to the indicies in Q
    s            Take the sum
 q               Is the above equal to...
  vz             z as an integer
               Implicit print of the remaining results
```